# How to embed an entity to another in datastore (php)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-api-php-client

I am trying to integrate `google datastore` api in `php`. I got succeed in creating an entity using compute engine application. I am using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to link to google nosql database. But now I want to create a following entity

```
users(kind){
   email:"abc@abc.com"
   name:"abc"
   password: "test"
   address (kind){
      id:XXXXXXX
      address:bla bla bla
   }
}
```

But there is no good documentation available to accomplish this in php. I am badly stuck. Can anyone guide me how can I do it using above library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create another kind `address` and set under the entity data type for address attribute in `users` entity.